# Why is my attempt to append to an NSMutableArray not adding anything?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have, inside a loop which populates on-screen elements:

```
        NSLog(@"Adding one card.");
        [self.cards addObject:noteView];
        NSLog(@"%d", [self.cards count]);
```

This generates a bunch of lines of output like:

```
Adding one card.
0
```

I've tried to initialize self.cards:

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    self.cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

Is there anything more I can do to initialize the array or add UIViews to it?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `init` constructor and not some other one?

Comment: First check to make sure your `init` method is actually being called.

Comment: Add a check wether your noteView object is nil.

Comment: NSMutableArray would throw exception if you added a nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, I just told you in another question 5 min ago.

Check that:

1. The init method is being called.
2. The addObject line is called.

You can put breakpoints on them

Comment: 2. would cause an exception, so he'd know about that right away.

Comment: Right, let me edit it